# Highlighting and editing Grids

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I currently have a gridview that is populated via database through a c# method.

I wanted to know if there was a way to select the row when clicked anywhere on the row and not use the select button altogether.  And then have the information from that row be sent back and populate another area on the webpage.

Is there a grid better than gridview for this?  Should I outsource to jQuery?  Or is gridview all I should need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is develop a row-clickable GridView. Best bet is to follow the instructions in the link. If your okay with VB, you can go along that route. A user has also converted it into C#, its in the comments section. Ill include it incase you dont see it.

Heres a link I have saved: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2006/01/07/14576.aspx

```
using System; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 

namespace CustomGridView 
{ 
 /// <summary> 
 /// Summary description for ClickableGridView 
 /// </summary> 
 public class ClickableGridView : GridView 
 { 
   public string RowCssClass 
   { 
     get 
     { 
       string rowClass = (string)ViewState["rowClass"]; 
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowClass)) 
         return rowClass; 
       else 
         return string.Empty; 
     } 
     set 
     { 
       ViewState["rowClass"] = value; 
     } 
   } 

   public string HoverRowCssClass 
   { 
     get 
     { 
       string hoverRowClass = (string)ViewState["hoverRowClass"]; 
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hoverRowClass)) 
         return hoverRowClass; 
       else 
         return string.Empty; 
     } 
     set 
     { 
       ViewState["hoverRowClass"] = value; 
     } 
   } 

   private static readonly object RowClickedEventKey = new object(); 

   public event GridViewRowClicked RowClicked; 
   protected virtual void OnRowClicked(GridViewRowClickedEventArgs e) 
   { 
     if (RowClicked != null) 
       RowClicked(this, e); 
   } 

   protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) 
   { 
     if (eventArgument.StartsWith("rc")) 
     { 
       int index = Int32.Parse(eventArgument.Substring(2)); 
       GridViewRowClickedEventArgs args = new GridViewRowClickedEventArgs(Rows[index]); 
       OnRowClicked(args); 
     } 
     else 
       base.RaisePostBackEvent(eventArgument); 
   } 

   protected override void PrepareControlHierarchy() 
   { 
     base.PrepareControlHierarchy(); 

     for (int i = 0; i < Rows.Count; i++) 
     { 
       string argsData = "rc" + Rows[i].RowIndex.ToString(); 
       Rows[i].Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, argsData)); 

       if (RowCssClass != string.Empty) 
         Rows[i].Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className='" + RowCssClass + "';"); 

       if (HoverRowCssClass != string.Empty) 
         Rows[i].Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='" + HoverRowCssClass + "';"); 
     } 
   } 
 } 

 public class GridViewRowClickedEventArgs : EventArgs 
 { 
   private GridViewRow _row; 

   public GridViewRowClickedEventArgs(GridViewRow aRow) 
     : base() 
   { 
     _row = aRow; 
   } 

   public GridViewRow Row 
   { 
     get 
     { return _row; } 
   } 
 } 

 public delegate void GridViewRowClicked(object sender, GridViewRowClickedEventArgs args); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am working in c# and have very limited knowledge with handlers.  Would I need to point the main handler code to my grid?  If so, how?